# Using faster-rcnn pycaffe in Windows fails with boost python error

Tags: python, windows, boost-python, caffe

I'm trying to run [py-faster-rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) in Windows, over static library build of Caffe with CPU only configuration.
It fails in GetPythonLayer in the following line:

```
bp::object layer = module.attr(param.python_param().layer().c_str())(param);
```

with the following error:

> TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: class
>   caffe::LayerParameter

Boost version: 1.58.
VC-14, x64, python 2.7 from Anaconda, Win8.1.

Any idea what could be the cause?

Much thanks!